# Eclipse Py-dev, dark theme remove text highlight during typing?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

When i  type a new word in eclipse pydev, it gets yellowishly higlited. Which makes it very difficult to read. How to remove this highlighting??

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that color in the preferences:

`General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Occurrences (PyDev)`